# How can I pass variable number of arguments to sprintf() function?

Tags: php, string, printf

In my web page, if a user choses certain options in a form, say

```
1. A -  Chosen
2. B -  Chosen
3. C -  Not Chosen
```

Then, sprintf() function in my script should accept that number of arguments -

```
sprintf("%s %s", valueOf(A), valueOf(B));
```

If all three are chosen, then

```
sprintf("%s %s %s", valueOf(A), valueOf(B), valueOf(C));
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I am wondering if you meant checkboxes instead of options?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you want is probably the [`vsprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.vsprintf.php) function.  It takes an array as the set of arguments.  So in your case, you'd have something like this:

```
$args = <array_of_chosen_options>;
$fmt = trim(str_repeat("%s ", count($args)));
$result = vsprintf($fmt, $args);
```

Comment: Why bother? Why not just `implode(' ', <array_of_chosen_options>)`?

Comment: @DaveRandom Of course, in the simple scenario in the question, `implode` would be a better solution, however in a more complex case, the formatting may be different for each selected element. `vsprintf` is a lot more flexible.

Comment: Thanks, nice and elegant solution!

Answer (score 3):

1. Generate the string of `%s %s...` dynamically
2. Use [`vsprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.vsprintf.php) instead of `sprintf`

```php
# // FOR DEMONSTRATION \\
$_POST["A"] = "subscribe_to_this";
$_POST["B"] = "subscribe_to_that";
# \\ FOR DEMONSTRATION //

$chosen = array();
if (isset($_POST["A"])) $chosen[] = $_POST["A"];
if (isset($_POST["B"])) $chosen[] = $_POST["B"];
if (isset($_POST["C"])) $chosen[] = $_POST["C"];

$format = implode(" ", array_fill(0, count($chosen), "%s"));
echo vsprintf($format, $chosen);
```

Comment: Why bother? Why not just `implode(' ', <array_of_chosen_options>)`?

Comment: @DaveRandom: Well, for my case, sprintf() is more cleaner. Actaully, It is a SQL query placeholder which I have. ("INSERT into ABC ('%s','%s'...)").

Answer (score 0):

`sprintf()` is not really the way to do this. It is intended for static strings with dynamic place holders, not dynamic strings with an unknown number of place holders.

All your chosen options, no matter how you collected them, will probably end up in an array. So you could just [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) it, like this:

```
$arr = array(
  'Chosen option',
  'Another option'
  // ...
);

$str = implode(' ', $arr);
```

Yes, you could `vsprintf()` it, but why bother with the extra overhead of producing a format string which must be parsed and interpolated?

Answer (score 0):

`sprintf` wouldn't be the ideal approach. Assuming that your HTML looks like

```
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="A" /> A
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="B" /> B
...
```

You can just do

```
$s = implode(" ", $_POST['options']);
```