# Sprintf-like formatting with optional parameters

Tags: php, printf

I am displaying address data that is pulled from customer-supplied records, and trying to format it properly. Each client can specify how they want their customer data to appear, so I am using an editable JSON-based template for each client that makes use of php's [sprintf()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) and it's formatting capability.

So client A, wanting their addresses to appear like:

```
Bill Smith
123 Fake St
Whoville, OH
```

Would have a saved format of `%s<br>%s<br>%s, %s`.

Client B wants:

```
Bill Smith
123 Fake St, Whoville, OH 94301
```

With a saved format of `%s<br>%s, %s, %s %s`

I then store these formattings in a client-specific template that tells me which fields to pull from and the format, i.e:

```
{
    "fields": [
        "full_name",
        "street",
        "city",
        "state",
        "zip"
    ],
    "format": "%s<br>%s, %s, %s %s"
}
```

Decoding the JSON, pulling the data and writing it using [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) with the supplied format works well, and doesn't require me creating a custom formatting function to handle the various address formats. **The problem is that if a piece of data is empty, it gets displayed**, i.e. if the street address is missing, we have:

```
Bill Smith
, Whoville, OH 94301
```

I am trying to come up with a solution that doesn't require re-inventing the wheel, but am open to other architectures that will give me the flexibility to handle 'optional' data with corresponding flexible formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found and implemented a solution that works rather well, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9924340/357801).

Essentially, I am breaking up the formatting components and matching them with the data components, so that I have something like:

```
{
  "data": "Bill Smith",
  "format": "%s"
},
{
  "data": "123 Fake St",
  "format": "<br>%s,"
},
{
  "data": "Whoville",
  "format": " %s,"
},
{
  "data": "OH",
  "format": " %s"
}
```

When I run through the above components, I then check for a value in .data and if found, concatenate the format component to a format variable. At the end, I run the data components and the concatenated format string through [`vsprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.vsprintf.php). Not perfect, but working better than before and fairly flexible.